# Rankine-Hugoniot condition for non piecewise smooth solutions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations, transport-equation

I studied the following theorem:(Rankine-Hugoniot condition)

Let u:ℝ×[0,+∞)→ℝ
u
:
R
×
[
0
,
+
∞
)
→
R
 be a piecewise $C^1$
 function. Then u is a weak solution of the conservation law if and only if the two of the following conditions are satisfied:

i) u
is a classical solution of in the domain where u
u is $C^1$

ii) u satisfies the jump condition

$(u_+−u_−)\eta_t+∑_{j=1}^d f_j(u+)−f_j(u−)η_x=0$

My Doubts:
i) Can we get the RH conditions for weaker assumptions on the solutions?

ii)If the solution $u\in BV$ then we know that $u_+$ and $u_-$  exists(though may not be equal) in such case can we apply RH condition?
For example , let $u$ be a measurable function which is a weak solution of the conservation law , can we say that for any real number $a$, $u(a+,t)=u(a-,t)$ for a.e $t>0$